# Google Sheets Script: Find First Date Earlier Than Target Date

Tags: google-apps-script

Using GoogleFinance to load historical data into a sheet, I'm trying to find the last Trading Date for a given year and month in a script function. So I use a for loop, going backwards, to compare dates and find the first date that is earlier than the first day of the month following the target month.

But I have an error in the way I'm checking for this. A check code segment is:

```
  if ( aSource[j][0] < analysisDate ) { rv = 'NO'; } else { rv = 'YES'; }
  ui.alert('SourceDate    =' + aSource[j][0] +
          '\nAnalysisDate =' + analysisDate +
          '\nIs SourceDate before AnalysisDate:  ' + rv);
```

The result is:
[image]

I must be using the operator incorrectly, but I haven't been able to find an example that shows how to do it, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really seem like an "answer", but...

I swapped the less-than (<) for greater-than (>) in the code shown in my post, and got the result I would have expected!

Why Jun 24 2021 **<** Jun 01 2021 returns TRUE, I have no idea. Seems like a script bug to me???